# Integrating Calendar in Android application

Tags: android, calendar, integration

I'm developing an Android application which requires a reminder similar to Google Calendar. The user should be able to insert new event.

Since I think is too complex write the interface from scratch, I would to know if there is a way for integrating any calendar in my application.

Answer (score 3):

[CalendarView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html) might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

here are two permissions to read/write calendar.

```
android.permission.READ_CALENDAR
android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR
```

Put these permissions into your AndroidManifest.xml. Then you will be able to manipulate the content provider used by the default calendar app.

```
calanderURL = "content://com.android.calendar/calendars";  //Calendar
calanderEventURL = "content://com.android.calendar/events";  //Events
calanderRemiderURL = "content://com.android.calendar/reminders"; //Reminders
```

There are many tutorials like [Working with the Android Calendar](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar-3850276.htm) on how to work with calendar.

You can read the data from calendar providers and display them in a [CalendarView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html)

Answer (score 0):

The ordinary `CalendarView` starts available in **Android 3.0 (HoneyComb)**.

Perhaps this third-party library can help you to bring calendar functionality up till **Android 2.1 (Eclair)**

https://github.com/SimonVT/android-calendarview